# How do you create SPSS syntax files (.sps) using a system other then SPSS?

Tags: python, spss

I have a python script that generates text files containing SPSS syntax.  Currently I have to copy the syntax from the text file and paste into an empty .sps file in order to run the syntax.  I need to automatically generate .sps files, either using a python script, or any other automated method, because I have thousands of analyses to run.

I tried to generate a single large SPSS syntax file via my python script and then paste that into a single SPSS syntax file, but that doesn't solve the issue because the resulting syntax file is to large and crashes SPSS, so I need to be able to create multiple seperate files.

How do you create SPSS syntax files (.sps) outside of the SPSS GUI?

Comment: .sps files are just text files. Since you have a Python script that writes text files it would seem that all you need to do is to change the statement that opens the output file so that it creates files with the .sps extension rather than files with (say) the .txt extension.

Comment: I second @BillBell's answer - just write out to "YourSyntax.sps"

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created the syntax file, which can havce any extension, you execute it by executing an INSERT command pointing to the file.

You can also execute it directly from a Python script without creating a file by using the spss.Submit api.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your problem. As comments indicate are SPSS syntax files just plain text files, which can be any size. The problems you are having probably arise when trying to run/execute the syntax. You mention thousands of analyses. Can it be that the output generated is too large and your SPSS crashes?

Comment: I didn't realize that .sps files were simply text files. I upvoted @BillBell's comment, though I couldn't select it as a correct answer.  This solved my issue.